# Copy active cell row and insert copied row directly underneath

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the active cell row and want to insert the copied row directly beneath that row. Like so:

```
Row 1   < User clicks relevant cell to trigger macro (Active Row)
Row 2   < Copied Cell gets inserted directly beneath Active Row
```

I want this to happen even if there is a row already below my Active Row i.e. this, when user clicks to copy Active Row:

```
Row 1 < Active Row
Row 2 < Other Content
```

Would turn into this:

```
Row 1 < Active Row
Row 2   < Copied Cell gets inserted directly beneath Active Row
Row 3 < Other Content
```

Here is my code which I have tried to put together with no luck:

```
'Add Tender Type Row
Dim NextRow As Range
Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("Home").ActiveCell.Rows.Count + 1)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing And Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "+" Then
Sheet1.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
Sheet1.Activate
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=1, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Please can someone show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You definition of `NextRow` was wrong, you used `Sheets("Home").ActiveCell.Rows.Count + 1` instead of `ActiveCell.Row + 1`

Give this a try :

```
Sub Mark_Harris()

Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    NextRow As Range

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Home")


With Ws
    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)) Is Nothing And .Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "+" Then
        .Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Set NextRow = .Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1)
        .Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
        NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=1, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```